# What's the minimum version of Chrome supporting localStorage?

Tags: json, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest, local-storage

I'm making a Chrome extension, and need to enter a `minimum_chrome_version` in my manifest file. My extension uses the HTML5 `localStorage` for it's options page. What's the minimum Chrome version with this or to support this? Windows and Mac preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/), Chrome's supported [web storage since (at most) version 4.](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) The Chrome versions are the same across all platform releases (Mac, Linux, and PC).

Answer (score 0):

The respective V8 binding dates back to June, 2009, which agrees with the Chrome version 4 in the other response. However Chrome keeps users [semi]automatically updated all the time, and hence I believe this question is not that important. You may well specify something around Chrome 12, since there should be no active users with an earlier version (the current stable channel version is 17, and the new versions are released about once a month.)

Comment: Agreed - Chrome is so good about keeping itself updated, and version 4 is so long ago, what's it matter?